# Facebook Graph API Testing Page / Post Insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am currently building an app that will pull in various site's insight data however I don't have access to these sites while still in development. Insights require at least 30 likes to provide the data. Are there any resources available for testing Facebook pages without this?